# Design of a 3 Phase Linear Induction Motor

Tags: electrical-engineering, electromagnetism, linear-motors

I am a Mechanical Engineer but need to use a 3 Phase Linear Induction Motor (LIM) for a MagLev project.

To demonstrate the working of LIM I need to design LIM for accelerating a 10 kg payload to speeds up to 30 m/s in any duration and up to any distance.

I have already obtained a smaller working LIM which accelerates a 0.7 kg Secondary (Aluminum plate with steel inside) to 4 m/s over a distance of 2 m. While having no access to original designer of this smaller Lim, still it can be reversed to higher scale under guidance by this auspicious forum
Thanks

Comment: I would probably start by hiring a EE.  Creating the field will be the hard part.

Comment: You didn't ask a question. This is a Q&A site (and not a discussion forum) so you need to ask a specific answerable question. See the [Tour] for more.